# Problems using Annotorious on web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, annotations, openseadragon

I have a problem using Annotorious over my page web.
I have to display OpenSeaDragon pictures,on my page, what I did, and be able to annotate images.
I used the source code of this page http://annotorious.github.io/demos/openseadragon-preview.html , but it doen't work, I see the button "add annotate" on my page but all, i can't select the zone to write something.
Need help please, this is my source code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <?php include 'includes/navbar.php' ?> 
       <?php include 'includes/connect_bdd.php';?>

    <title>Annotorious - Image Annotation for the Web</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="annotorious/css/highlight.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="openseadragon.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="annotorious/annotorious.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map-annotate-button {
        position:absolute;
        top:3px;
        right:3px;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
        padding:3px 8px;
        z-index:10000;
        font-size:11px;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function annotate() {
        var button = document.getElementById('map-annotate-button');
        button.style.color = '#777';

        anno.activateSelector(function() {
          // Reset button style
          button.style.color = '#fff';
        });
      }

      function init() {             
        var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
          id: "openseadragon",
          prefixUrl: "images/",
          showNavigator: false,
          tileSources:"PhotoDzi/TCGA-BH-A1ES-01Z-00-DX1.C54C809F-748F-4BB0-B018-A8A83A4134C0.svs.dzi"
        });
        
        anno.makeAnnotatable(viewer);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()";>
            
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-inner">
        <div style="position:relative; width:640px; height:400px; margin-bottom:20px;">
          <div id="openseadragon" style="width:640px; height:400px; background-color:#fff;"></div>
          <a id="map-annotate-button" onclick="annotate(); return false;" href="#">ADD ANNOTATION</a>
        </div>

         <h4>About</h4>
            <?php
            $req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM miniatures WHERE titre=\'' . $_GET['titre'] . '\'');
            $image = $req->fetch();
            ?> 

            <?php
            $req->closeCursor();
            ?>
          </div>
        </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
            
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('pre.code').highlight({source:0, zebra:1, indent:'space', list:'ol'});
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If no one answers here, you might try asking at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/annotorious or https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious/issues

Comment: Sorry to knitpick, especially since abominations like 'download install' are apparently acceptable in Silicon Valley Newspeak, but 'add annotate' is way over the line. Please, it's either 'add annotation', or just 'annotate'. (P.S: Congratulates on your promote.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with latest Openseadragon and my own dzi and took out
php and inserted some text and just replaced the hightlight.css with

"/theme-dark/annotorious-dark.css"

and it seems to work..